# Android/Kotlin: Intent always NULL

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, bundle

I have searched through multiple posts on here which seem to all have the same problem but with different causes. I am getting NULL results from my bundle when calling them from the second activity. I will post more of my code if required;

Here is where i package my bundle on initial activity:

```
    val extras = Bundle()
    extras.putString("EXTRA_DIFFICULTY", dif_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
    extras.putString("EXTRA_CAT", cat_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
    intent.putExtras(extras)
```

And when I am in my second activity:

```
    val bundle :Bundle ?=intent.extras
    val difficultystring = bundle?.getString("EXTRA_DIFFICULTY")
    val catstring = bundle?.getString("EXTRA_CAT")
    txtV.text = "Your difficulty level is " + difficultystring + " and your cat is " + catstring
```

In both cases it return null. The spinners initialise on create so there should always be a value to call, can anyone point me in the right direction please?

FULL CODE (less functions - not causing any issues)

Activity 1

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var btnSTART: Button
    lateinit var switchSNOW: Switch
    lateinit var imageviewSNOW: ImageView
    lateinit var requested_difficulty: String
    lateinit var dif_spinner: Spinner
    lateinit var cat_spinner: Spinner
    var difficulty_array = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        dif_spinner = findViewById(R.id.difficulty_spinner)
        cat_spinner = findViewById(R.id.cat_spinner)
        switchSNOW = findViewById(R.id.snow_switch) as Switch
        imageviewSNOW = findViewById(R.id.imageViewSnow) as ImageView

        imageviewSNOW.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        switchSNOW.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if(isChecked){
                imageviewSNOW.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                imageviewSNOW.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }


        btnSTART = findViewById(R.id.buttonSTART) as Button
        btnSTART.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, Quiz::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.difficulty_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            dif_spinner.adapter = adapter
        }
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.cat_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            cat_spinner.adapter = adapter
        }
        val extras = Bundle()
        extras.putString("EXTRA_DIFFICULTY", dif_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
        extras.putString("EXTRA_CAT", cat_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
        intent.putExtras(extras)

    }
}
```

Activity 2

```
class Quiz : AppCompatActivity() {
        lateinit var txtV: TextView
        lateinit var btn1: Button
        lateinit var btn2: Button
        lateinit var btn3: Button
        lateinit var btn4: Button
        lateinit var viewQ: TextView
        var ans: Int = 0

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz)




        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button1) as Button
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2) as Button
        btn3 = findViewById(R.id.button3) as Button
        btn4 = findViewById(R.id.button4) as Button
        viewQ = findViewById(R.id.textview_question)
        txtV = findViewById(R.id.textView_info) as TextView


            ans = GetQuestion(1, rand(1, 6))

        btn1.setOnClickListener{


            val theirans: String = btn1.getText().toString() //this will get a string
            val TheirAnswer = theirans.toInt() //this will get a no from the string

                if(TheirAnswer==ans) {
                    btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lime_green);
                } else {
                    btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
                }
                    next()
            };
        btn2.setOnClickListener {

            val theirans: String = btn2.getText().toString() //this will get a string
            val TheirAnswer = theirans.toInt() //this will get a no from the string
            if(TheirAnswer==ans) {
                btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lime_green);
            } else {
                btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
            }
            next()
        };
        btn3.setOnClickListener{

            val theirans: String = btn3.getText().toString() //this will get a string
            val TheirAnswer = theirans.toInt() //this will get a no from the string
            if(TheirAnswer==ans) {
                btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lime_green);
            } else {
                btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
            }
            next()
        };
        btn4.setOnClickListener{

            val theirans: String = btn4.getText().toString() //this will get a string
            val TheirAnswer = theirans.toInt() //this will get a no from the string
            if(TheirAnswer==ans) {
                btn4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lime_green);
            } else {
                btn4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
            }
            next()
        };

            val bundle :Bundle ?=intent.extras

            val difficultystring = bundle?.getString("EXTRA_DIFFICULTY")
            val catstring = bundle?.getString("EXTRA_CAT")
            txtV.text = "Your difficulty level is " + difficultystring + " and your category is " + catstring
}
```

Comment: In your second code snippet, where is `bundle` coming from?

Comment: `The spinners initialise on create so there should always be a value to call` do you know this for a fact ? have you logged it/debugged it ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited my code above. I missed a line when copying over to here sorry

Comment: put `dif_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()` into a `Log` and track them

Comment: In your **second code snippet**, where is `bundle` coming from? Your edit was to the first code snippet.

Comment: @a_local_nobody everything I have read about spinners is that they always initialise on create which is why you have to be careful with listeners to ensure you call the value selected by the user rather than the default value. I don't use a listener as I capture the information at a point in time

Comment: @CommonsWare corrected again, sorry

Comment: Share full code.

Comment: i update answer can you try with that

Comment: Can we see the `startActivity(intent)`?

Comment: full code added

Comment: @cutiko thank you.... your simple question was in fact the answer...I put my bundle in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question raised by @cutiko provided the answer to my problem. For some reason I added the bundle to the end of my code rather than with my start activity intent.

From activity 1 my code went from:

```
btnSTART.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, Quiz::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
}
```

&

```
    val extras = Bundle()
    extras.putString("EXTRA_DIFFICULTY", dif_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
    extras.putString("EXTRA_CAT", cat_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
    intent.putExtras(extras)
```

to

```
btnSTART.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, Quiz::class.java)
            val extras = Bundle()
            extras.putString("EXTRA_DIFFICULTY", dif_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
            extras.putString("EXTRA_CAT", cat_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
            intent.putExtras(extras)
            startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if the linter showed a warning for shadowed Java bean properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use below answer

```
   val intent = intent
   val difficultystring = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_DIFFICULTY")
    val catstring = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_CAT")
    txtV.text = "Your difficulty level is " + difficultystring + " and your cat is " + catstring
```

Comment: I started with that but getStringExtra is not recognised and suggests I rename the reference or create extension function Bundle?.getStringExtra. Others who used bundle were using just getString

Comment: result is the same